# Insert Blob Data into Sqlite3 (GeoPackage)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, geo

I having issues writing WKB or Well Known Binary into a sqlite database/geopackage (they are the same type of database).

Here is the create statement to generate a polyline dataset.

```sql
CREATE TABLE line 
(OBJECTID INTEGER primary key autoincrement not null, 
Shape MULTILINESTRING)
```

The WKB is as follows:

```py
bytearray(b'\x01\x05\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x96C\x8b\x9a\xd0@`\xc18\xd6\xc5=\xd2\xc5RA\x93\xa9\x825\x02=`\xc1\xb0Y\xf5\xd1\xed\xa6RAZd;W\x913`\xc1 Zd\xfb\x1c\xc0RA\xaa\x82Q%p/`\xc18\xcd;\x92\x19\xaeRA\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00z\xc7)TzD`\xc1\xb8\x8d\x06\xb8S\x9fRA\xbb\xb8\x8d:{"`\xc1X\xec/\xb7\xbb\x9eRA\x00\x91~Eo"`\xc1\x00\xb3{F\xff]RA')
```

When I go to insert the binary data into the column, I do not get an error, it just inserts NULL.

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO line (Shape)
                 VALUES(?)"""
val = [binaryfromabove]
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

I've also tried using `sqlite3.Binary()` as well:

```py
sql = """INSERT INTO line (Shape)
                 VALUES(?)"""
val = [sqlite3.Binary(binaryfromabove)]
cur.execute(sql, val)
```

The row that is insert is always NULL.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: have you tried using `GeomFromWKB(wkb)` in insert query?

Comment: I'm using Pure Python for this only

Comment: **Works for me**, `'SELECT * FROM line'` gives the `Shape` as inserted.

Comment: I think I need to use register_converter and set sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES to detect_types when I create the connection.